# Listen ModalBottomSheetLayout state change in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Currently I am using ModalBottomSheetLayout to display the bottom sheet.

I don't know is there a way to listen to the bottom page closing event?

Comment: Can you please share some code that you've written to display sheet? And I wanted to clarify you want `closing` event or completely `closed/collapsed` event?

Comment: hi @MayurGajra. thank you for support. i was find my solution  as below

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In Compose to listen for changes you need to check current values of your mutable states.

In case with `ModalBottomSheetLayout` you have [`ModalBottomSheetState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ModalBottomSheetState), and you can check on `currentValue` of this state. If you need you can modify your views state depending on this value.

If you wanna perform some action on state changes, you need to use [side effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects). The most basic one is [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary?hl=vi#LaunchedEffect(kotlin.Any,kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)), you can use it in combination with `snapshotFlow` to watch any state value:

```kotlin
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    snapshotFlow { modalBottomSheetState.currentValue }
        .collect {
            println(it.toString())
        }
}
```

Also I'll be called first time when you launch a screen, and you'll have `Hidden` there too, so depending on your needs it may not be an ideal solution.

---

To get the most close to listening on becoming hidden, you can use [`DisposableEffect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary?hl=vi#DisposableEffect(kotlin.Any,kotlin.Function1)).

```kotlin
if (modalBottomSheetState.currentValue != ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden) {
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose {
            println("hidden")
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm launching `DisposableEffect` when your sheet appears, and when it disappears - I'm removing it from the view hierarchy, which will cause the `onDispose` to be called.

Full example of basically everything you can do with the state:

```kotlin
val modalBottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
LaunchedEffect(modalBottomSheetState.currentValue) {
    println(modalBottomSheetState.currentValue)
}
if (modalBottomSheetState.currentValue != ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden) {
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose {
            println("hidden")
        }
    }
}
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
    sheetContent = {
        Text(
            "sheetContent",
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
        )
    }
) {
    Column {
        Text(modalBottomSheetState.currentValue.toString())
        Button(onClick = {
            scope.launch {
                modalBottomSheetState.show()
            }
        }) {
            Text("Show bottom sheet")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Philip Dukhov. Thank you so much. The solution is the best.

Comment: In LaunchedEffect the key can not be Unit - the key should be bottomSheetState

Answer (score 29):

You can just use `confirmStateChange` from `rememberModalBottomSheetState`:

```
val state = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden, confirmStateChange = {
   if (it == ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden) {
       println(it)
   }
   true
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. I will take note of your answer

Comment: Worked nicely for me. Seems to be called earlier than @Pylyp Dukhov's answer, which is beneficial for my usecase

Comment: Having `confirmStateChange` makes the sheetContent flicker on recomposition

Answer (score 11):

Using `confirmStateChange` won't be invoked however if you `show/hide` the modal yourself with a `clickable` for example - it seems to only be invoked on clicking the scrim or swiping.

A way around this is to just observe the [`modalBottomSheetState.targetValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/SwipeableState#targetValue()) which will change anytime the modal is animating between two different states:

```kotlin
LaunchedEffect(modalBottomSheetState.targetValue) {
    if (modalBottomSheetState.targetValue == ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden) {
        // do something when animating to Hidden state
      } else {
        // expanding
      }
}
```

This is closer to the timing of `confirmStateChange` which is invoked before the call to `show/hide`. Observing `modalBottomSheetState.currentValue` will change at the end of the animation, while `modalBottomSheetState.targetValue` will change before the animation begins.