# How to get slideOffset in jetpack compose's BottomSheetScaffold widget?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-bottomsheetdialog

In old way, I can use **slideOffset** in `BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback`. But now in Jetpack compose, I can't use **slideOffset**. How to get it?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69052933/3585796) on how you can track state changes in compose, in case of `BottomSheetScaffold` you're probably looking for `scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.currentValue`

Comment: This may not working. `scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.currentValue` is enum value, *Collapsed* or *Expanded*. What I want to use is the slide offset value, from 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: I found the `bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.offset` variable, but I don't know how to use it. I tried `LaunchedEffect(bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.offset.value)`,  only called once, and the bottom content can not slide.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I meant `scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.currentValue`, but to me it works fine to me with [this code](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/6ff432f49a5876ad3f7f13bee47c4295). Show how you're trying to use it. Also I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69052660/listen-modalbottomsheetlayout-state-change-in-jetpack-compose/69052933#69052933) with a more performant version which uses `snapshotFlow`, check it out too

Comment: Thanks bro. Finally I found a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69529798/how-to-expand-bottomsheetscaffold-to-a-specific-height-at-with-jetpack-compose). Also I will try your code later.